# Need some help figuring out how to do 2 things in my C program

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement 2 things in my program in C. I don't think is necessary to show you the code as I simply want to know if they're possible to be done. I've searched this but couldn't find any clear answer.

I have this program in C, with many functions, main() and 3 "sub menus".
The main is basically just the main menu of the program and it contains a which case to go to the other sub menus, and each of those sub menus go to the functions related to them.
What I want to know is how to make those functions return to those sub menus, instead of going back all the way to main().
In each of those functions I have a "return;" at the end, but they return to main and not the sub menu. It would be great to get some clarity on this.

My other question is if it's possible to go back to the sub menu, before or while entering data in a function from that sub menu, by pressing the backspace key, or maybe give a key the job to, when pressed, cancel the function (as if, I clicked this function by mistake and want to go back) and go back to the sub menu.

I'd really appreciate some help, and if needed I can post the code, or parts of it as it's still pretty big, to give some context (but bare in mind that all the variables, names of the functions, printf's and what not are in portuguese).

EDIT:
Here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define NR 1000

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

typedef struct
{
  int idJogo;
  char nomeJogo[50];
  char genero[50];
  char empresa[50];
  char plataforma[50];
  long int preco;
  int estado; // 1 - Ocupado e 0 - Livre
}jogo;

typedef struct
{
  int idCliente;
  char nomeCliente[50];
  long int contacto;
  char cidade[50];
  int estado; // 1 - Ocupado e 0 - Livre
}cliente;

typedef struct
{
  int idCompra;
  int idCliente;
  int idJogo;
  char nomeJogo[50];
  char nomeCliente[50];
  char dataCompra[20];
  long int valor;
  int estado; // 1 - Ocupado e 0 - Livre
}compra;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////// FICHEIROS //////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////// Ler Ficheiros ////////////////////////////////////

int lerficheiros (jogo *jogo, cliente *cliente, compra *compra)
{
  int m, n, o;
  printf("\n\tA carregar os ficheiros...\n\n");
  FILE *fj, *fc, *fk;

  // Verifica se existe o ficheiro txt dos jogos
  if(!(fj=fopen("jogos.txt", "r")))
  {
    printf("\n\n\tO ficheiro de jogos não existe. <Enter> para criar o ficheiro.");getch();
    // Cria o ficheiro caso não exista
    fj=fopen("jogos.txt", "w");
    printf("\n\tO ficheiro dos jogos foi criado.");
  }
  // Lê o ficheiro dos jogos
  fj=fopen("jogos.txt", "r");
  for (m=1; m<NR; m++)
  {
    fscanf(fj, "%d\n", &jogo[m].idJogo);
    fscanf(fj, "%s\n", jogo[m].nomeJogo);
    fscanf(fj, "%s\n", jogo[m].genero);
    fscanf(fj, "%s\n", jogo[m].empresa);
    fscanf(fj, "%s\n", jogo[m].plataforma);
    fscanf(fj, "%ld\n", &jogo[m].preco);
    fscanf(fj, "%d\n", &jogo[m].estado);
  }
  fclose(fj);
  printf("\n\tFicheiro dos jogos lido <Enter> para continuar.\n");getch();

  //Igual para o ficheiro dos clientes
  if(!(fc=fopen("clientes.txt", "r")))
  {
    printf("\n\n\tO ficheiro de clientes não existe. <Enter> para criar o ficheiro.");getch();
    // Cria o ficheiro caso não exista
    fc=fopen("clientes.txt", "w");
    printf("\n\tO ficheiro dos clientes foi criado.");
  }
  // Lê o ficheiro dos clientes
  fc=fopen("clientes.txt", "r");
  for (n=1; n<NR; n++)
  {
    fscanf(fc, "%d\n", &cliente[n].idCliente);
    fscanf(fc, "%s\n", cliente[n].nomeCliente);
    fscanf(fc, "%ld\n", &cliente[n].contacto);
    fscanf(fc, "%s\n", cliente[n].cidade);
    fscanf(fc, "%d\n", &cliente[n].estado);
  }
  fclose(fc);
  printf("\n\tFicheiro dos clientes lido <Enter> para continuar.\n");getch();

  //Mais uma vez igual para o ficheiro das compras
  if(!(fk=fopen("compras.txt", "r")))
  {
    printf("\n\n\tO ficheiro de compras não existe. <Enter> para criar o ficheiro.");getch();
    // Cria o ficheiro caso não exista
    fk=fopen("compras.txt", "w");
    printf("\n\tO ficheiro de compras foi criado.");
  }
  // Lê o ficheiro das compras
  fk=fopen("compras.txt", "r");
  for (o=1; o<NR; o++)
  {
    fscanf(fk, "%d\n", &compra[o].idCompra);
    fscanf(fk, "%d\n", &compra[o].idCliente);
    fscanf(fk, "%d\n", &compra[o].idJogo);
    fscanf(fk, "%s\n", compra[o].nomeJogo);
    fscanf(fk, "%s\n", compra[o].nomeCliente);
    fscanf(fk, "%s\n", compra[o].dataCompra);
    fscanf(fk, "%ld\n", &compra[o].valor);
    fscanf(fk, "%d\n", &compra[o].estado);
  }
  fclose(fk);
  printf("\n\tFicheiro de compras lido <Enter> para continuar.\n");getch();

}

///////////////////////////// Gravar Ficheiros /////////////////////////////////

void gravarficheiros(char sair, jogo *jogo, cliente *cliente, compra *compra)
{
  int m, n, o;
  FILE *fj, *fc, *fk;

  // Grava ficheiro dos jogos

  fj=fopen("jogos.txt", "w");
  for(m=1;m<NR;m++)
    {
        if(jogo[m].estado==1)
        {
            fprintf(fj,"%d\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%ld\n%d\n",jogo[m].idJogo,jogo[m].nomeJogo,
      jogo[m].genero,jogo[m].empresa,jogo[m].plataforma,jogo[m].preco,jogo[m].estado);
        }
    }
    fclose(fj);

  // Grava ficheiro dos clientes

  fc=fopen("clientes.txt", "w");
  for(n=1;n<NR;n++)
    {
        if(cliente[n].estado==1)
        {
            fprintf(fc,"%d\n%s\n%ld\n%s\n%d\n",cliente[n].idCliente,cliente[n].nomeCliente,
      cliente[n].contacto,cliente[n].cidade,cliente[n].estado);
        }
    }
    fclose(fc);

  // Grava ficheiro de compras

  fk=fopen("compras.txt", "w");
  for(o=1;o<NR;o++)
    {
        if(compra[o].estado==1)
        {
            fprintf(fk,"%d\n%d\n%d\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%ld\n%d\n",compra[o].idCompra,compra[o].idCliente,
      compra[o].idJogo,compra[o].nomeJogo,compra[o].nomeCliente,compra[o].dataCompra,
      compra[o].valor,compra[o].estado);
        }
    }
    fclose(fj);

  if (sair=='S') exit(0);
    printf("\n\n\n\tFicheiros gravados <Enter> para continuar."); getch();

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////// JOGOS //////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////// Consultar Jogos //////////////////////////////////

int consultarjogos(jogo *jogo)
{
  int n;
  system ("cls");
  printf("\n----------------------- LISTA DE JOGOS -----------------------\n");
  for(n=1;n<NR;n++)
  {
    if(jogo[n].estado==1)
    {
      printf("\n\tID: %d | Nome: %s | Genero: %s\n\tEmpresa: %s | ", jogo[n].idJogo, jogo[n].nomeJogo, jogo[n].genero, jogo[n].empresa);
      printf("Plataforma: %s | Preco: %ld€\n", jogo[n].plataforma, jogo[n].preco);
    }
  }
  printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("\n\tListagem concluída. <Enter> para continuar.");
  getch();
}

///////////////////////////// Inserir Jogo /////////////////////////////////////

int inserirjogo(jogo *jogo)
{
  int n;
  system ("cls");
  fflush(stdin);
  printf("\n----------------------- INSERIR JOGO -----------------------\n");
  for(n=1;n<NR;n++)
  {
    if(jogo[n].estado!=1)
    {
      jogo[n].idJogo=rand() % 999;
      printf("\n\tNome do Jogo -> "); gets(jogo[n].nomeJogo);
      printf("\n\tGenero -> "); gets(jogo[n].genero);
      printf("\n\tEmpresa -> "); gets(jogo[n].empresa);
      printf("\n\tPlataforma -> "); gets(jogo[n].plataforma);
      printf("\n\tPreco (€) -> "); scanf("%ld", &jogo[n].preco); fflush(stdin);
      jogo[n].estado=1;
      printf("\n\n------------------------------------------------------------\n");
      printf("\n\tJogo inserido. <Enter> para continuar.");
      getch();
      return(0);
    }
  }
  printf("\n\tErro, não foi possivel inserir o jogo. <Enter> para continuar.");
  getch(); return(1);
}

/////////////////////////////// Alterar Jogo ///////////////////////////////////

int alterarjogo(jogo *jogo)
{
  int n;
  long int altjogo;
  system("cls");
  printf("\n----------------------- ALTERAR JOGO -----------------------\n");
  printf("\n\tID do Jogo que pretende alterar: ");
  scanf("%d", &altjogo); fflush(stdin);
  for(n=1;n<NR;n++)
  {
    if(jogo[n].idJogo==altjogo)
    {
      jogo[n].estado=0;
      printf("\n\n\tID: %d | Nome: %s | Genero: %s\n\tEmpresa: %s | ", jogo[n].idJogo, jogo[n].nomeJogo, jogo[n].genero, jogo[n].empresa);
      printf("Plataforma: %s | Preco: %ld€", jogo[n].plataforma, jogo[n].preco);
      printf("\n\n\tNome do Jogo -> "); gets(jogo[n].nomeJogo);
      printf("\n\tGenero -> "); gets(jogo[n].genero);
      printf("\n\tEmpresa -> "); gets(jogo[n].empresa);
      printf("\n\tPlataforma -> "); gets(jogo[n].plataforma);
      printf("\n\tPreco (€) -> "); scanf("%ld", &jogo[n].preco); fflush(stdin);
      jogo[n].estado=1;
      printf("\n\n------------------------------------------------------------\n");
      printf("\n\tJogo alterado. <Enter> para continuar.");
      getch();
      return(0);
    }
  }
  printf("\n\tErro, jogo não encontrado. <Enter> para continuar.");
    getch(); return(1);
}

/////////////////////////////// Eliminar Jogo //////////////////////////////////

int eliminarjogo(jogo *jogo)
{
  char conf;
  int n;
  long int elimjogo;
  system("cls");
  printf("\n----------------------- ELIMINAR JOGO -----------------------\n");
  printf("\n\tID do Jogo que pretende eliminar: ");
  scanf("%ld", &elimjogo); fflush(stdin);
  for(n=1;n<NR;n++)
  {
    if(jogo[n].idJogo==elimjogo)
    {
      printf("\n\n\tID: %d | Nome: %s | Genero: %s\n\tEmpresa: %s | ", jogo[n].idJogo, jogo[n].nomeJogo, jogo[n].genero, jogo[n].empresa);
      printf("Plataforma: %s | Preco: %ld€", jogo[n].plataforma, jogo[n].preco);
      printf("\n\n\tTem a certeza que quer eliminar o jogo? <S/N>");
      conf=toupper(getch());
      if (conf!='S') return(1);
      jogo[n].estado=0;
      printf("\n\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
      printf("\n\tJogo eliminado. <Enter> para continuar.");
      getch();
      return(0);
    }
  }
  printf("\n\tErro, jogo não encontrado. <Enter> para continuar.");
  getch(); return(1);
}

///////////////////////////// Menu Gerir Jogos /////////////////////////////////

int gerirjogos(jogo *jogo)
{
  system("cls");
  char op;
  do {
    printf("\n----------------------- GERIR JOGOS -----------------------\n");
    printf("\n\t 1 - Consultar Jogos\n\t 2 - Inserir Jogo\n\t 3 - Alterar Jogo\n\t 4 - Eliminar Jogo\n\t 0 - Voltar");
    printf("\n\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\n\t Opcao:"); op=getch();
  } while(op<'0' || op>'4');
  switch (op){
    case '1': consultarjogos(jogo); break;
    case '2': inserirjogo(jogo);    break;
    case '3': alterarjogo(jogo);    break;
    case '4': eliminarjogo(jogo);   break;
    case '0': return(0);            break;
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////// CLIENTES /////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

////////////////////////// Consultar Clientes //////////////////////////////////

int consultarclientes(cliente *cliente)
{
  int n;
  system ("cls");
  printf("\n----------------------- LISTA DE CLIENTES -----------------------\n");
  for(n=1;n<NR;n++)
  {
    if(cliente[n].estado==1)
    {
      printf("\n\tID: %d | Nome: %s", cliente[n].idCliente, cliente[n].nomeCliente);
      printf("\n\tContacto: %ld | Cidade: %s\n", cliente[n].contacto, cliente[n].cidade);
    }
  }
  printf("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("\n\tListagem concluída. <Enter> para continuar.");
  getch();
}

///////////////////////////// Inserir Cliente //////////////////////////////////

int inserircliente(cliente *cliente)
{
  int n;
  system ("cls");
  fflush(stdin);
  printf("\n----------------------- INSERIR CLIENTE -----------------------\n");
  for(n=1;n<NR;n++)
  {
    if(cliente[n].estado!=1)
    {
      cliente[n].idCliente=rand() % 999;
      printf("\n\tNome do Cliente -> "); gets(cliente[n].nomeCliente);
      printf("\n\tContacto -> "); scanf("%ld", &cliente[n].contacto); fflush(stdin);
      printf("\n\tCidade -> "); gets(cliente[n].cidade);
      cliente[n].estado=1;
      printf("\n\n---------------------------------------------------------------\n");
      printf("\n\tCliente inserido. <Enter> para continuar.");
      getch(); return(0);
    }
  }
  printf("\n\tErro, não foi possivel inserir o cliente. <Enter> para continuar.");
  getch(); return(1);
}

/////////////////////////////// Alterar Cliente ////////////////////////////////

int alterarcliente(cliente *cliente)
{
  int n;
  long int altcliente;
  system("cls");
  printf("\n----------------------- ALTERAR CLIENTE -----------------------\n");
  printf("\n\tID do Cliente que pretende eliminar: ");
  scanf("%d", &altcliente); fflush(stdin);
  for(n=1;n<NR;n++)
  {
    if(cliente[n].idCliente==altcliente)
    {
      cliente[n].estado=0;
      printf("\n\n\tID: %d | Nome: %s | ", cliente[n].idCliente, cliente[n].nomeCliente);
      printf("\n\tContacto: %ld | Cidade: %s", cliente[n].contacto, cliente[n].cidade);
      printf("\n\n\tNome do Cliente -> "); gets(cliente[n].nomeCliente);
      printf("\n\tContacto -> "); scanf("%ld", &cliente[n].contacto); fflush(stdin);
      printf("\n\tCidade -> "); gets(cliente[n].cidade);
      cliente[n].estado=1;
      printf("\n\n---------------------------------------------------------------\n");
      printf("\n\tCliente alterado. <Enter> para continuar.");
      getch(); return(0);
    }
  }
  printf("Erro, cliente não encontrado. <Enter> para continuar.");
    getch(); return(1);
}

//////////////////////////// Eliminar Cliente //////////////////////////////////

int eliminarcliente(cliente *cliente)
{
  char conf;
  int n;
  long int elimcliente;
  system("cls");
  printf("\n----------------------- ELIMINAR CLIENTE -----------------------\n");
  printf("\n\tID do Cliente que pretende eliminar: ");
  scanf("%ld", &elimcliente); fflush(stdin);
  for(n=1;n<NR;n++)
  {
    if(cliente[n].idCliente==elimcliente)
    {
      printf("\n\n\tID: %d | Nome: %s | ", cliente[n].idCliente, cliente[n].nomeCliente);
      printf("\n\tContacto: %ld | Cidade: %s", cliente[n].contacto, cliente[n].cidade);
      printf("\n\n\tTem a certeza que quer eliminar o cliente? <S/N>");
      conf=toupper(getch());
      if (conf!='S') return(1);
      cliente[n].estado=0;
      printf("\n\n----------------------------------------------------------------\n");
      printf("\n\tCliente eliminado. <Enter> para continuar.");
      getch();
      return(0);
    }
  }
  printf("\n\tErro, cliente não encontrado. <Enter> para continuar.");
  getch(); return(1);
}

///////////////////////////// Menu Gerir Clientes //////////////////////////////

int gerirclientes(cliente *cliente)
{
  system("cls");
  char op;
  do {
    printf("\n----------------------- GERIR CLIENTES -----------------------\n");
    printf("\n\t 1 - Consultar Clientes\n\t 2 - Inserir Cliente\n\t 3 - Alterar Cliente\n\t 4 - Eliminar Cliente\n\t 0 - Voltar");
    printf("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\n\t Opcao:"); op=getch();
  } while(op<'0' || op>'4');
  switch (op){
    case '1': consultarclientes(cliente); break;
    case '2': inserircliente(cliente);    break;
    case '3': alterarcliente(cliente);    break;
    case '4': eliminarcliente(cliente);   break;
    case '0': return(0);                  break;
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////// COMPRAS //////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////// Consultar Compras ////////////////////////////////

int consultarcompras(compra *compra)
{
  int n;
  system ("cls");
  printf("\n----------------------- REGISTO DE COMPRAS -----------------------\n");
  for(n=1;n<NR;n++)
  {
    if(compra[n].estado==1)
    {
      printf("\n\tID Compra: %d | ID Jogo: %d | ID Cliente: %d", compra[n].idCompra, compra[n].idJogo, compra[n].idCliente);
      printf("\n\tNome do Jogo: %s | Nome do Cliente: %s", compra[n].nomeJogo, compra[n].nomeCliente);
      printf("\n\tData da Compra: %s | Valor da Compra: %ld€\n", compra[n].dataCompra, compra[n].valor);
    }
  }
  printf("\n------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("\n\tListagem concluída. <Enter> para continuar.");
  getch();
}

///////////////////////////////// Nova Compra //////////////////////////////////

int novacompra(compra *compra, jogo *jogo, cliente *cliente)
{
  int n, m, o, idj, idc;
  system ("cls");
  printf("\n----------------------- NOVA COMPRA -----------------------\n");
  for(n=1;n<NR;n++)
  {
    if(compra[n].estado!=1)
    {
      compra[n].idCompra=rand() % 999;
      printf("\n\tID do Jogo -> "); scanf("%d", &idj); fflush(stdin);
      for(m=1;m<NR;m++)
      {
        if(jogo[m].idJogo == idj)
        {
          printf("\n\tNome do Jogo: %s", jogo[m].nomeJogo);
          compra[n].idJogo = jogo[m].idJogo;
          strcpy(compra[n].nomeJogo, jogo[m].nomeJogo);
          compra[n].valor = jogo[m].preco;
          printf("\n\n\tID do Cliente -> "); scanf("%d", &idc); fflush(stdin);
          for(o=1;o<NR;o++)
          {
            if(cliente[o].idCliente == idc)
            {
              printf("\n\tNome do Cliente: %s", cliente[o].nomeCliente);
              compra[n].idCliente = cliente[o].idCliente;
              strcpy(compra[n].nomeCliente, cliente[o].nomeCliente);
              printf("\n\n\tData da Compra (dd/mm/aaaa) -> "); scanf("%s", compra[n].dataCompra);
              printf("\n\tValor: %ld€", compra[n].valor);
              compra[n].estado=1;
              printf("\n\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n");
              printf("\n\tCompra registada. <Enter> para continuar.");
              getch(); return(0);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  printf("\n\tErro, não foi possivel concluir a compra. <Enter> para continuar.");
  getch(); return(1);
}

//////////////////////////// Eliminar Compra ///////////////////////////////////

int eliminarcompra(compra *compra)
{
  char conf;
  int n;
  long int elimcompra;
  system("cls");
  printf("\n----------------------- ELIMINAR COMPRA -----------------------\n");
  printf("\n\tID da Compra que pretende eliminar: ");
  scanf("%ld", &elimcompra); fflush(stdin);
  for(n=1;n<NR;n++)
  {
    if(compra[n].idCompra==elimcompra)
    {
      printf("\n\n\tID Compra: %d | ID Jogo: %d | ID Cliente: %d", compra[n].idCompra, compra[n].idJogo, compra[n].idCliente);
      printf("\n\tNome do Jogo: %s | Nome do Cliente: %s", compra[n].nomeJogo, compra[n].nomeCliente);
      printf("\n\tData da Compra: %s | Valor da Compra: %ld€", compra[n].dataCompra, compra[n].valor);
      printf("\n\n\tTem a certeza que quer eliminar a compra? <S/N>");
      conf=toupper(getch());
      if (conf!='S') return(1);
      compra[n].estado=0;
      printf("\n\n---------------------------------------------------------------\n");
      printf("\n\tCompra eliminada. <Enter> para continuar.");
      getch();
      return(0);
    }
  }
  printf("\n\tErro, registo da compra não encontrado. <Enter> para continuar.");
  getch(); return(1);
}

///////////////////////////// Menu Gerir Compras ///////////////////////////////

int gerircompras(compra *compra, jogo *jogo, cliente *cliente)
{
  system("cls");
  char op;
  do {
    printf("\n----------------------- GERIR COMPRAS -----------------------\n");
    printf("\n\t 1 - Consultar Compras\n\t 2 - Nova Compra\n\t 3 - Eliminar Compra\n\t 0 - Voltar");
    printf("\n\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\n\t Opcao:"); op=getch();
  } while(op<'0' || op>'3');
  switch (op){
    case '1': consultarcompras(compra);                break;
    case '2': novacompra(compra, jogo, cliente);       break;
    case '3': eliminarcompra(compra);                  break;
    case '0': return(0);                               break;
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////// MAIN /////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

main()
{
  system("COLOR 1F");
  char op, sair='N';
  int n;
  srand(time(NULL));
  jogo jogo[NR];
  cliente cliente[NR];
  compra compra[NR];
  system ("chcp 1252");
  for(n=1;n<NR;n++)
  {
    jogo[n].estado=0;
    cliente[n].estado=0;
    compra[n].estado=0;
  }
  lerficheiros(jogo, cliente, compra);
  for(;;)
  {
  do
  {
    system("cls");
    printf("\n----------------------- LOJA DE JOGOS -----------------------\n");
    printf("\n\t 1 - Gerir Jogos\n\t 2 - Gerir Clientes\n\t 3 - Gerir Compras");
    printf("\n\t 4 - Ler Ficheiros\n\t 5 - Gravar Ficheiros \n\t 0 - Sair");
    printf("\n\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\n\t Opcao:"); op=getch();
  }while (op<'0' || op>'5');
  switch (op) {
    case '1': gerirjogos(jogo);                                break;
    case '2': gerirclientes(cliente);                          break;
    case '3': gerircompras(compra, jogo, cliente);             break;
    case '4': lerficheiros(jogo, cliente, compra);             break;
    case '5': gravarficheiros(sair, jogo, cliente, compra);    break;
    case '0': sair='S'; gravarficheiros(sair, jogo, cliente, compra);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: The first one is easy to do by putting a loop in the submenu functions. The second one is harder, since for example, the backspace key is handled by the keyboard driver and never reaches your program.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as too broad... (oops.... I don't have enough points to my account). Point is, you're handing us a bunch of questions with no fragments of code relevant to the question.

Comment: It's impossible to explain why *In each of those functions I have a "return* at the end but they return to main and not the sub menu* without seeing the code you're using. Regarding your second question, yes. It's possible. It's also impossible to tell you how to do so in your current code, because **we can't see your current code**. Do yourself a major favor: spend some time in the [help], particularly the [How do I ask a good question here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), before posting your next question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void pause(void);
void print_result(char **menu, int ret);
void clrscr(void);

#define MENU_INPUT(a)   menu_input(a,sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a))


char * main_menu[]={
    "Display First Menu",
    "Display Sencond Menu"
    };

 char * first_menu[]={
    "Format Drive C:",
    "Partition First Drive",
    "Scan Drive"
    };
char * second_menu[]={
    "Display an image",
    "Play a sound"
    };


int menu_input(char **menu,int items){
    int i, j;

    clrscr();

    for(i = 1; i<=items;i++)
        printf(" %d - %s\n",i, menu[i-1]);

    printf(" 0 - to cancel\n ");

    do{
        scanf("%d", &i);
    }while( i < 0 || i > items);

    return i;   
}





int main(void){
    int ret;
    for( ; ; ){
        switch( MENU_INPUT( main_menu ) ){
            case 0:
                return 0;
            case 1:
                ret = MENU_INPUT( first_menu );
                print_result( first_menu, ret );
                break;
            case 2:
                ret= MENU_INPUT(second_menu);
                print_result( second_menu, ret );
       }
    }

    return 0;
}


// these are some helpper functions

void pause(void){
    char c;
    printf("press enter to continue\n");
    scanf(" %c", &c);
}


void print_result(char **menu, int ret){
    if( ret ){
        printf("You pressed %d (%s)\n", ret, first_menu[ ret - 1 ] );
        pause();
    }
}


// clear screen
void clrscr(void){
#ifdef WIN32
    char *cmd = "cls";
#else
    char *cmd = "tput reset";
#endif

    system(cmd);
}
```

Comment: I'll try this out, thanks :)